# Running scripts from Greasemonkey4IE

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to call a method defined in my .js file (the one I will load into greasemonkey) automatically?
what I mean by automatically is I don't want to create an html file to call that...
Is there some way to use use "script" tags without creating html file.
Here I am trying to create a simple UI with a button for example.

The code to create the button will be in the .js file.

Any ideas ???
Thanks

Comment: you don't need tags if you are using an external js file

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
(function(){
   // gets executed immediately
})();
```